# spark sql - whether to use row transformation or UDF

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am having an input table (I) with 100 columns and 10 million records. I want to get an output table (O) that has 50 columns and these columns are derived from columns of I i.e. there will be 50 functions that map column(s) of I to 50 columns of O i.e. *o1 = f(i1) , o2 = f(i2, i3) ..., o50 = f(i50, i60, i70)*.

In spark sql I can do this in two ways:

1. row transformation where entire row of I is parsed (ex: map function) one by one to produce a row of O.
2. Use UDF which I guess work at column level i.e. take existing column(s) of I as input and produce one of the corresponding column of O i.e. use 50 UDF functions.

I want to know which one of the above 2 is more efficient (higher distributed and parallel processing) and why or if they are equally *fast/performant*, given that I am processing entire input table I and producing entirely new output table O i.e. its a bulk data processing.

Comment: Hi sunillp, I'm facing the exact dilemma between row vs column wise transformations as you described. Could you please share experience - what did you end up doing and how was the performance finally? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I was going to write this whole thing about the [Catalyst optimizer](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html), but it is simpler just to note what Jacek Laskowski says in his book *Mastering Apache Spark 2*:

"*Use the higher-level standard Column-based functions with Dataset operators whenever possible before reverting to using your own custom UDF functions since UDFs are a blackbox for Spark and so it does not even try to optimize them.*"

Jacek also notes a comment from someone on the Spark development team:

"*There are simple cases in which we can analyze the UDFs byte code and infer what it is doing, but it is pretty difficult to do in general.*"

This is why Spark UDFs should never be your first option.

That same sentiment is echoed in this Cloudera [post](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/02/working-with-udfs-in-apache-spark/), where the author states "*...using Apache Spark’s built-in SQL query functions will often lead to the best performance and should be the first approach considered whenever introducing a UDF can be avoided.*"

However, the author correctly notes also that this may change in the future as Spark gets smarter, and in the meantime, you can use `Expression.genCode`, as described in Chris Fregly’s [talk](https://www.slideshare.net/cfregly/advanced-apache-spark-meetup-project-tungsten-nov-12-2015), if you don't mind tightly coupling to the Catalyst optimizer.

Comment: I am some what not clear on this. The function say "f(x)" (in scala) that I use for transformation will be same irrespective of whether I use it as a map function (for row based transformation) or as a UDF (for column based transformation). So in both cases spark will have optimization issues?

Comment: It's not that black-and-white. Optimization is a spectrum. UDFs are the least optimizable. From there you can optimize further by using `DataFrames` with `Columns`, by using [built-in library functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) when possible, by taking advantage of storage optimizations support between Spark and storage formats like Parquet, etc. You also don't have to guess. You can interrogate Spark for its logical and physical plans in multiple scenarios to see what's more efficient and which changes have the most impact.

Comment: Thanks for the link to generating your own code! I think that's a great way to port some existing "optimized" (from a Java standpoint) routines over to Spark, and reusing "legacy" C-Code inside a modern framework. I wonder how much effort and complexity there would be in having pluggable code-generation backends, so even hand tuned assembler code could be directly generated, rather than having to wrap it in C. Of course, that's a corner case, and support for optimized libraries covers 98% of requirements.

Answer (score 4):

User define functions or custom functions can be defined and registered as UDFs in Spark SQL with an associated alias that is made available to SQL queries.

UDF has major performance impact over Apache Spark SQL ([Spark SQL’s Catalyst Optimizer](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html))

Since we don't have any defined rules in Spark and developer can use his/her due diligence.

**Python UDF**  never use UDF. it's impossible compensate the cost of repeated serialization, deserialization and data movement between Python interpreter and JVM, Python UDFs result on in data being serialized between the executor JVM and the Python interpreter running the UDF logic – this significantly reduces performance as compared to UDF implementations in Java or Scala.

**Java, Scala UDF** implementation is accessible directly by the executor JVM.  **So Java ,Scala UDF performance is better then Python UDF**

**Spark SQL** functions operate directly on JVM and optimize with both Catalyst and Tungsten. It means these can be optimized in the execution plan and most of the time can benefit from codgen and other Tungsten optimizations. Moreover these can operate on data in its "native" representation., since Spark SQL to be working with Catalyst query optimizer. Its capabilities are expanding with every release and can often provide dramatic performance improvements to Spark SQL queries;

**Conclusion** :
UDF implementation code may not be well understood by Catalyst ,So using Apache Spark’s built-in SQL query functions will often lead to the best performance and should be the first approach considered whenever introducing a UDF can be avoided.

Comment: do you have an example?

Answer (score 2):

In simple cases using UDF is a much better choice because it doesn't require a full encoding and decoding. UDF can access only the required fields and encode the result.

Since Spark 2.0 it is also much better supported and can be, up to some extent, optimized in the execution plan.

Both mapping a full `Row` and applying a standard UDF cannot benefit from all Spark SQL optimizations and there is no difference in terms of data distribution and parallelization.

Comment: So UDF is more efficient than the row-based transformation using map function with custom logic, when the builtin column functions cannot complete the same task?

Answer (score 1):

Spark has [inbuilt functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) to have `new dataframe` by using `parent dataframe`'s columns.

These functions would perform better than the two proposed choices of using `udf` functions or using `row` transformations.

Writing `row` transformation functions for the 50 required columns of the final table considering optimized distribution of data would be a real trouble.

If your functions (`o1 = f(i1) , o2 = f(i2, i3) ..., o50 = f(i50, i60, i70)`) cannot be replaced by [inbuilt functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) or the combination of them, then only I would suggest you to go with `udf` functions as udf functions would require data to be serialized and deserialized.