# Apache Spark - Adding a incremental Id in based on a column value

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to create an incremental id in based on a column value.

For example if I have the following table

```
-----------------------
| id |   value    |
-----------------------
| 3  |    a       |
| 2  |    a       | 
| 1  |    b       |
| 4  |    b       |
| 5  |    c       |
-----------------------
```

I would like to create a new column with a random or incremental identifier that is unique for the columen value like the following:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| id |   value    |    new_id    |
-----------------------------------------------
| 3  |    a       |     1        | 
| 2  |    a       |     1        |
| 1  |    b       |     2        |
| 4  |    b       |     2        |
| 5  |    c       |     3        |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Is there any option apart of using a distinct and joining later?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One straight forward way is to get a hash of the column value. This should be a collision-free hash and will prevent a scan of the entire data set.

Using scala,

```
val sparkSession = ???
import sparkSession.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = ???
val dfModified = df.withColumn("new_id", hash(col("value")).cast("string"))
```

Note, if you have a fixed known set of values, then you should create a `value -> id` map beforehand and use broadcast join or UDF to put new IDs. If you're not using scala, the approach will be the same, you just have to use a different hashing technique.

Hope this helps, Cheers.

Comment: That would fit the requirement but UDFs are slow and best avoided if possible.

Comment: no, they aren't, they are basically `map` operations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43411234/spark-sql-whether-to-use-row-transformation-or-udf

Comment: The post just mentions the well-known fact that UDFs mostly can not be optimised. In this case it okay, since there is no complex transformation, theres a `string => map` transformation. Nevertheless, I updated the answer to use inbuilt `hash` function which again uses the same implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dense_rank() and order by value in your Window however this will move all data to a single partition so will perform poorly for large DataSets.

```
val window =   Window.orderBy($"value")

df.withColumn("new_id", dense_rank.over(window))
```

Edit - it appears that using a dummy partition ensures the data is shuffled into spark.sql.shuffle.partitions partitions

```
val window =   Window.partitionBy(lit(0)).orderBy($"value")
```